# Parallel execution of the same @Sceduled method

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I have e method which is annotated with @scheduled. Its a fairly long running method. I need to run the same method in parallel using a threadpool. Is it possible? The code is:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=100)
public void run() {
    Job job = QUEUE.take();
    job.run(); //Takes a long time
}
```

The QUEUE has many jobs and I would like to run them in parallel using Spring's Scheduled annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the Job.run method to an Asynchronous methods by use spring's "@Async",or another way you can create yourself threadpool to do the Job.

```
/**
 * Created by roman.luo on 2016/9/14.
 */
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class JobDelegate implements Job {

    private Job job;

    public JobDelegate(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    @Async
    public void run(){
        job.run();
    }
}

/**
 * Created by roman.luo on 2016/9/14.
 */
@Component
public class Sceduled extends ApplicationObjectSupport{

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 100)
    public void run(){
        Job job = QUEUE.take();
        Job jobDelegate = getApplicationContext().getBean(JobDelegate.class,job);
        jobDelegate.run();
    }

}
```

remember config the spring xml file:

```
<task:executor id="myexecutor" pool-size="5"  />  
<task:annotation-driven executor="myexecutor"/>
```